# reanimated version problem (couldn't determine the version of the native part of Reanimated.)

Tags: react-native, expo, pinchzoom, react-native-reanimated, react-native-reanimated-v2

I am trying to practive this video.

https://youtu.be/R7vyLItMQJw
(The basics of PinchGestureHandler with React Native Reanimated 2)

but my app doesn't work touch.

I get this Error

[Reanimated] Couldn't determine the version of the native part of Reanimated.Did you forget to re-build the app after upgrading react-native-reanimated? If you use Expo Go, you must use the exact version which is bundled into Expo SDK.

How can I solve this problem?

first. I upgraded Expo SDK.

but I got still same error.

second. re-build the app.

but I got still same error.

third. I install reanimated again. but still be same error.

Comment: I fixed the same problem running ```npm install```

Comment: Any luck with this? I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 4):

That is because the Reanimated version you installed is not compatible with your expo package version. try running this in terminal:

```
expo doctor --fix-dependencies
```

then run

```
expo start
```

or

```
npm start
```

whatever command you usually enter to open your development server

Answer (score 0):

I was having the very same problem right now.
The following solved my issue:

```
npx expo start --clear
```

Hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/guides/troubleshooting/#couldnt-determine-the-version-of-the-native-part-of-reanimated)
This happens when Reanimated fails to determine the version of its native part. Check if you have rebuilt your app after upgrading react-native-reanimated. If you use Expo Go, you must use the exact version that is bundled into Expo SDK.
I uninstalled the previously installed react-native-reanimated using `npm uninstall react-native-reanimated` and then used this command `npx expo install react-native-reanimated`  which installs the compatible version of reanimated with expo SDK